# How to find all users in a department in Microsoft Graph API V1.0

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below Microsoft Graph API api call to get Department name but using User id:

```
 var Peoples = await graphServiceClient.Users[user.Id].People.Request().GetAsync();
  foreach (Person People in Peoples)
                                        {
                                            if (People.DisplayName != null && People.DisplayName.Equals(user.DisplayName))
                                            {
                                                Console.Writeline(People.Department)

                                            }
                                        }
```

Now,i want to get all users in a Department(Where Department Name will be given as input) .

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) parameter.

the code will change to the following

```
 var Peoples = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Filter("department eq 'departname '").GetAsync();
```

Comment: Hi @kalyan But , inititally i will not be having user id. I have to find department users based on only one input that is Department Name.

Comment: It was throwing exception 'Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid filter clause .                                                                            
 But i changed the code to :                                                                                  var Peoples1 = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Filter("department eq 'IT Admin'").Select(u => new {
                u.DisplayName,
                u.MobilePhone,
                u.UserPrincipalName
            }).GetAsync();
Thanks a lot Kalyan.  You can remove $filter from your answer.